# Java Regex to split numbers with unknown number of spaces

Tags: java, regex

I have a string of numbers that are a little weird.  The source I'm pulling from has a non-standard formatting and I'm trying to switch from a .split where I need to specify an exact method to split on (2 spaces, 3 spaces, etc.) to a replaceall regex.

My data looks like this:

```
23574     123451    81239   1234    19274  4312457     1234719
```

I want to end up with

```
23574,xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxx
```

So I can just do a String.split on the ,

Comment: Why do you want to split it, join back to a string, and split again?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I will use `\s` Regex

This is its usage on Java

```
String[] numbers = myString.split("\\s+");
```

Comment: This worked out amazingly well, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: As an aside, do you know of any decent tutorials on learning regex?  It seems like a ton of people know them, but never have a concrete source on where to read up about them.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/ and http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html Are the ones I have bookmarked for any REGEX related question I have

Comment: That looks pretty interesting.

Answer (score 3):

```
final Iterable<String> splitted = Splitter.on('').trimResults().omitEmptyStrings().split(input);
final String output = Joiner.on(',').join(splitted);
```

with Guava [`Splitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) and [`Joiner`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
String pattern = "(\s+)";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher match = r.matcher(inputString);
match.replaceAll(",");
String stringToSplit = match.toString();
```

I think that should do it for you. If not, googling for the Matcher and Pattern classes in the java api will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this problem as a way to obtain integer numbers from a string with blank (not only space) separators.

The accepted solution does not work if the separator is a TAB `\t` for instance or if it has an `\n` at the end.

If we define an integer number as a sequence of digits, the best way to solve this is using a simple regular expression. Checking the [Java 8 Pattern API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), we can find that `\D` represents any non digit character:

> ```
> \D  A non-digit: [^0-9]
> ```

So if the `String.split()` method accepts a regular expression with the possible separators, it is easy to send `"\\D+"` to a trimmed string and get the result in one shot like this.

```
String source = "23574     123451    81239   1234    19274  4312457     1234719";
String trimmed = source.trim();
String[] numbers = trimmed.split("\\D+");
```

It is translated as ***split this trimmed string using any non digit character sequence as a possible separator***.